# Calculate Storage for Backup in Azure - which type should I use?

Tags: azure, video, storage, calculation

we are considering using Azure Storage for our Backup of our NAS.

First, I want to tell you how our environment locally looks like.

- We do have a NAS with 4 TB capacity.
- On the NAS we are saving our recorded videos, which were taken by our GoPro. The Video Records are separated by folder. Each Video Record does contain files like .MP4, LRV and .THM. Per Video Record there could be around 50 files / items. Each Video Record can contain about 50 files. Sometimes there are also some pictures (JPG).
- Actually, we do have a data around 450 GB.

What we want to do is save these data to Azure Storage.

Important for us is:

- The storage does not have to be performant. Because they are just storage for backup.
- It should only charge me the consume that I needed. So, if I buy a Azure Storage which is 1TB, but I'm only using 500 GB, it should me charge the 500GB and not the 1TB.
- The storage should be resizable. That means, one day, if the 1TB Storage for example is not enough anymore, I should be able to increase the size to 2TB, 5TB or 10TB.

Now what I do was start to calculate that with Azure Calculator. But there are many options, which makes me a little bit confusing, even I was now researching the meaning for few days.

First of all I'm not sure which of the Storage Type is the correct one for me. Is it the Block Blob storage or Disk Storage? If its Disk Storage, which one should I prefer, managed or unmanaged disk?

Thank you for your cooperation.

---

**Additional questions - Part 1:**

**@Gaurav Mantri**, thank you for your detailed and informative answer.

So I choosed in the Azure Calculator the Block Blob Storage with Genereal Purpose V2. I have two questions:

- Is it possible to attach the Blob Storage to a VM in Azure?
- How many "Operations" should I calculate in my case, if let's say the data which is will backup every day is 450 GB (the actual data size) then once per week there data size will increase for 50GB. So the question is, how many "write operations" / "List and Create
  Container Operations" / "Read operations means" should I calculate?

---

**Additional questions - Part 2:**

**@Gaurav Mantri**, thank you for your additional answers :-).
We are almost there that I understand how it works.

I just made the calculation and saw that there is a second section with options with more or less the same meaning. At least for me.

There is the first section with "**Write operations**", "**List and Create Container Operations**" and "**Read operations**". Which I think I do understand it now.

The second section is about "**All other operations**", "**Data retrieval**" and "**Data write**".

So my question is what is the meaning of the second section?

I mean they are nearly same like the options from the first section.

- What does it mean with "**all other operations**" - do you have an example?
- What does it mean with "**Data write**"? Is that not the same like "**Write operations**" from the first section.
- I believe "**Data retrieval**" is just a additional charge, when I'm uploading some data to Azure Storage.
- Lets say, if I assume to use full of the 1 TB storage, do I have to enter the value 1 TB for "**Data retrieval**" and "**Data write**"? So does it just make sense to have the same value, than the size of the Storage that i calculate?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to answer some of your questions:

> It should only charge me the consume that I needed. So, if I buy a
>   Azure Storage which is 1TB, but I'm only using 500 GB, it should me
>   charge the 500GB and not the 1TB.

Azure Storage does exactly that. You only pay for the data that you store.

> The storage should be resizable. That means, one day, if the 1TB
>   Storage for example is not enough anymore, I should be able to
>   increase the size to 2TB, 5TB or 10TB.

Currently each Azure Storage account has an maximum size (which I believe is 5 PB which is 5000 TB). Based on your current consumption, it should be enough. In one of the presentations Microsoft mentioned that they are working on removing this limit as well. When that happens, you can possibly store infinite amount of data in that storage account. In the meantime if you exceed this limit, you can always create a new storage account and that will give you additional 5 PB of storage. In an Azure Subscription you can have a maximum of 100 storage accounts so even with this limit you can possibly store 500 PB of data.

> First of all I'm not sure which of the Storage Type is the correct one
>   for me. Is it the Block Blob storage or Disk Storage?

Since you mentioned that you want to backup the videos, my recommendation would be to use Block Blobs.

Since your primary reason to use Azure Storage is to create a backup of the videos, you may also want to look at `Archive Storage` available in Azure Storage if the data you're storing in Azure Storage is not going to be accessed that frequently. The plus side is that you pay even lesser storage price for archived data. The down side is that retrieval of archived data is expensive and time consuming. You may find this link useful in understanding more about blob tiering: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-storage-tiers.

**Additional Answers :)**

> Is it possible to attach the Blob Storage to a VM in Azure?

No, it is not possible to do so. If you need to attach storage to a VM in Azure, please look at File Storage.

> How many "Operations" should I calculate in my case, if let's say the
>   data which is will backup every day is 450 GB (the actual data size)
>   then once per week there data size will increase for 50GB. So the
>   question is, how many "write operations" / "List and Create Container
>   Operations" / "Read operations means" should I calculate?

It depends on what all operations you're performing. Let's say you're uploading 50GB of data / week (roughly 200 GB data / month). Further assume that your videos are big and you split all your videos in 1MB chunks then you're making approximately 200000 write operations/month (200 * 1024 MB / 1MB). If you're not reading anything (as they are backup), then you don't have to include listing and reading operations.

Comment: Can you please edit your post and include the follow up questions there? I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Updated my answer. HTH.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, unfortunately I was not to reply for private reasons. But thanks Gaurav Mantri for your answers!! Actually, there is a Part 2 of my additional questions. Maybe you can give an reply.

Comment: do you have any idea?